# In R Shiny how to embed HTML Radio buttons within a Table

Tags: html, r, radio-button, shiny, html-table

I'm trying to embed rows of radio buttons within a table in R/Shiny using HTML.  From Shiny HTML examples I can create rows of radio buttons and get the input values (input$a1value, input$a2value) but am unable to read those values when I wrap it in table HTML.  See code below:

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  mainPanel(
      uiOutput("htmltable"),
      textOutput("a1value"),
      textOutput("a2value")

  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$htmltable <- renderText({
    HTML('
       <table class="data table table-bordered table-condensed">
       <tr><td>

       <div id="a1" class="form-group shiny-input-radiogroup shiny-input-container">
       <label class="control-label" for="a1">Radio button in a table example </label>
       <div class="shiny-options-group">
       <div class="radio"> <td><label><input type="radio" name="a1" checked="checked" value="1"></label></td>
       </div><div class="radio"> <td><label><input type="radio" name="a1" value="2"> </label></td>
       </div><div class="radio"> <td><label><input type="radio" name="a1" value="3"> </label></td>
       </div><div class="radio"> <td><label><input type="radio" name="a1" value="4"> </label></td>
       </div><div class="radio"> <td><label><input type="radio" name="a1" value="5"> </label></td>
       </div></div></div>
       </td></tr>
       <tr><td>
       <div id="a2" class="form-group shiny-input-radiogroup shiny-input-container">
       <label class="control-label" for="a2"> </label>
       <div class="shiny-options-group">
       <div class="radio"> <td><label><input type="radio" name="a2" checked="checked" value="1"></label></td>
       </div><div class="radio"> <td><label><input type="radio" name="a2" value="2"> </label></td>
       </div><div class="radio"> <td><label><input type="radio" name="a2" value="3"> </label></td>
       </div><div class="radio"> <td><label><input type="radio" name="a2" value="4"> </label></td>
       </div><div class="radio"> <td><label><input type="radio" name="a2" value="5"> </label></td>
       </div></div></div>
       </td></tr> </table>')})

    output$a1value <- renderText({input$a1})
    output$a2value <- renderText({input$a2})

})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

I can get a1value and a2value before wrapping the HTML with the table HTML construct but not afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example using mtcars dataset

Our function to build the html table

`ff <- function(i)data.frame(vals = sprintf("<td>%s</td>",mtcars[i,1]),rads = sprintf('<td><div class="form-group shiny-input-container"><input name="row-%s" type="checkbox" id="row-%s" /><label for="row-%s">%s</label></div>',i,i,i,row.names(mtcars[i,])))`

precompile table elements

`a <- rbind.pages(lapply(1:15,function(x)ff(x)))`

For the headers

`ths <- paste("<tr>\n",paste0(paste0("<th>",colnames(a),"</th>"),collapse = "\n"),"\n</tr>",sep="") %>%HTML`

For the body

`tbods <- paste0(apply(a,1,function(i)sprintf("<tr>%s</tr>",paste0(i,collapse = ""))),collapse="\n")%>%HTML`

You would use renderUI on the server side

`tagList(tags$table(tags$head(ths),tags$tbody(tbods)))%>%html_print`

UPDATE:
I'm using the mtcars dataset

```
mtcars$html <- llply(1:nrow(mtcars),function(i)
HTML(sprintf('<div><input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="%s" class="our-class" id="%s"/> %s <label for="%s">%s</label></div>',i,row.names(mtcars)[[i]],i,row.names(mtcars)[[i]],row.names(mtcars)[[i]])))%>%unlist
```

NOTE:this is my function internally, but use the function we used before to make the table

```
aa<-rt.table_prep(mtcars)


tags$html(tags$head(tags$link(href = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"),tags$script(src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js")),tags$body(tags$div(class="container",tags$div(class="row",tags$div(id = "log",style="font-size:56px"),tags$table(tags$thead(aa[[1]]),tags$tbody(aa[[2]])))),tags$script(HTML("$('input').on('click',function(){$('#log').html($('input:checked').val()+'is checked');});"))))%>%html_print
```

which gives us:http://codepen.io/CarlBoneri/pen/YqOBBN

Comment: Thanks Carl.  You've shown a more elegant way to generate the table but I'm still having problems reading the values of the checkboxes.

Comment: Each checkbox has the I'd of the original row number. So input [[row-nth]] will access the values using a loop inside a reactive.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Carl.  Being an HTML and R newbie, can you show me what the reactive loop would look like?  Thanks again.

Comment: I'd be happy to, but first take a look at this example and see if it helps provide some clarity. I understand this stuff is tricky and for a 'newbie ' you're attempting something fairly complex. https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/blob/master/025-loop-ui/server.R

Comment: Wow, didn't know about the input [[ ]] access method.  Have it working for checkboxes but I need to have it work with radio buttons.  When I replace the checkboxes with radio buttons, I get NULL's for input access.  Do you know the changes needed to implement radio buttons? Thanks once again!

Comment: @user6253481 for reproduction sake...what values are you planning on putting in fo the radio buttons? i'd need to toy with it. The radio buttons on a quick try aren't toggling...which would be pretty useless in my opinion.  But i have to test something in the same light..so..give me a few

Comment: Just a simple numeric (eg,  value="1") for each button. Again, thank you for your help!

Comment: Should also note this eliminates the need for a loop reactive on the server side. Instead of div with Id "log" make it a text input and then server side is simply input $log

Comment: Amazing, the javascript did it! Thanks for your time/expertise!

Comment: Not a problem....happened to be working on a similar issue. Gotta ask, why radio buttons?

Comment: The rows are graph types, the columns represent files.  Each row can only select a single column, i.e., a single file selected to display a graph type.   It's a condensed and efficient way (visually) to configure a list of graphs for a dashboard, each graph displayed once and made up of a single file.

Comment: interesting! I'd love to see it in action! I'm assuming you're using the index selected to source the file that contains the graph code?

Comment: I can give you a screen shot with the names

Comment: changed. But don't know how/where to send it.

Comment: No worries..not sure what so rule is on publishing email addys...plus worst place I can think to do so haha

Comment: @user6253481 be sure to change the selector in the js otherwise it'll fire on any input event throughout your app. Sure you thought of that but figured I'd circle back as I thought about it.

Comment: Yes thanks. Took a little to implement it but it's now working.  Thanks again!